# Does Internet Recovery erase everything on my Mac?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, system-recovery

I accidentally booted into Internet Recovery when I meant to boot into Recovery Manager, will this erase everything on my Mac?

Answer (score 3):

Performing Internet Recovery does not delete your user data.

That said, it is advisable to have a backup ready before performing any other troubleshooting steps.

Under OS X starting with 10.6 (or 10.7?), in order to have *everything* on your hard drive deleted, you must open Disk Utility and manually reformat / repartition the drive. If you don't do this, only the OS X operating system will be reinstalled, without removing your user data.

So, to summarize, unless you remember going into Disk Utility or doing anything in there, your personal data should be there – even after a restore.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem! And thank you for the edit, apologies for the title and all.. I was panicking. I'll be sure to mark this as an answer as soon as it's done!

Comment: We've all been there! Now is the best time to start keeping a constant Time Machine backup of your Mac, I guess.

Comment: I'm emptying an HDD as we speak (87% complete)! Thanks again!

Comment: Panicking again... I can't boot into my Mac disk. I can only boot into my BOOTCAMP?

Comment: I have never used Boot Camp and therefore cannot give any specific advice. Perhaps it's better to ask a new question and include all the details, like what OS X version you have, what you installed through Boot Camp, what exactly you did (Internet Restore, anything else?), perhaps show the disk layout that you see in Disk Utility, etc.

Comment: It's been a while, but it'd be good to put a short update: Internet Recovery corrupted the main partition, but the Bootcamp partition survived. I booted into Windows, used File Explorer to go onto the main partition, and found all my files in one piece (which was rather strange). Copied everything over to the HDD, and then reinstalled OS X.