# Will Re-installing Mojave Through Internet Recovery Delete Data?

Tags: mac

As explained here, Internet Recovery does not delete your old data. [Does Internet Recovery erase everything on my Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/715991/does-internet-recovery-erase-everything-on-my-mac)

But what specifically function of Internet Recovery that won't delete your data?

> TL;DR I installed Catalina beta, and then used Internet Recovery to
>   re-install Mojave back. Files gone, but system data is 100GB+

Here's what I did. I installed MacOS Beta (Catalina), and I realized I can't submit iOS builds to App Store with this MacOS (believe me, I did everything I could including trying different Xcode builds and so on, and this is the last option I could do, reverting the system to Mojave).

So from Catalina, I restarted my macbook with my fingers holding COMMAND + OPTION + R. And then I got into that rotating globe thing, and I connected to wifi, and I waited 1 hour or so for this. And then at the last part of this adventure, I got into an option of downloading and eventually installing Mojave.

After installing Mojave, all of my files are gone, I was not surprised, I was expecting this. But not this:

[image]

I feel like my old apps are somewhere in my storage.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it!!! Thanks to the Macbook Users group on Facebook! Someone suggested `Disk Inventory X`. It's a free software, not to mention open-source. I knew it! My old files are there. I should've not downloaded huge developer apps before trying this.

[image]